# Get total %cpu,%mem for a process including all threads or sub processes?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface

Get total %cpu,%mem for a process including all threads or sub processes?

For example rsync if you do the following, you get the %cpu,%mem for the parent process only.  Where 9215 is pid of active rsync.

```
ps -p 9215 -o %cpu,%mem
```

How can one get the entire, total %cpu,%mem for the entire rsync process including its threads or sub processes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux, you can isolate a command to a cgroup and get its total resource use, even if it execs other processes.

For one-off commands on systemd systems, create a transient unit: `systemd-run --unit=run  rsync-script.sh`   where "run" is some descriptive name and "rsync-script.sh" is a script doing the thing. See resources by cgroup in `systemd-cgtop`.   Actually getting numbers requires enabling resource accounting by default, see `man systemd.resource-control`

---

Threads are the simple case that doesn't require fancy accounting to get. Processes report the CPU and private memory total of all their threads. Have a look at multiple threaded task groups with `pidstat -t`